# How can we put all photos from gallery to collectionview? I have this, but it does not work

Tags: swift

import UIKit

class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
private let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    pickerController.delegate = self

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

}
```

}
extension GalleryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayOfImages.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCollectionViewCell",
                                                       for: indexPath) as?  PhotoCollectionViewCell else {
    return UICollectionViewCell()
   }
    cell.imageView.image = arrayOfImages[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

}

extension GalleryViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo
                            info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let image = info [.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        arrayOfImages.append(image)
        print("added")
     self.collectionView.reloadData()
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    
    pickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Comment: Define "not working". What's happening? What's the code called? Did you check some values? Is `arrayOfImages` having the correct values, etc. ?

Comment: There are no mistakes, just collectionview is empty